# @3x image in app make in xcode 5, will iphone 6+ use it?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I'm finishing app in xcode 5. 
What if I will add @3x images except @2x, 1x? Will iphone 6+ use them

I have another question:
My app use graphics 
1x -320x300  (width x lenght) ; 
@2x-  640x600 (width x lenght) images. In iphone 5,4,3 this graphics are full width of display and almost half lenght .
I want do graphics for iphone 6+, the same - for full widht, and almost half display.

@3x must be 960x  (3x 320) and 900 (3x 300), 
or may be like display witdht in iphone 6+  (1242), and 1100 lenght.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it's not really a programming question.

Comment: The iPhone 6+ won't use @3x images unless you build in Xcode 6 and provide iPhone 6/6+ specific launch images.

Comment: hey @maddy - do you know, is it correct that Xcode won't "work" with @ 3x images, unless, you have the launch-images there?  SO, if you don't have launch-images there, Xcode doesn't treat a @ 3x image as @ 3x - it treats it as if no extension on the name. Does that sound right?